# sudo apt update is not working

Tags: 20.04, lts

E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list (Suite)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

my source.list file is as below:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210819)]/ focal main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
# deb-src http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
# deb-src http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
# deb-src http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
# deb-src http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

Comment: What is the error exactly you are getting , what you tried and other details are must for getting a good answer.

Comment: tried to run this command 'sudo apt update'

Comment: deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted This is the line the error is complaining about. Maybe #it out for now and try to run apt again. 4 th line down in your display.

Comment: still getting the same error
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list (Suite)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the result of ```sudo apt update``` mark it with code fences.

Comment: The error is in line 1 of the file mentioned in your message `etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list`  .. on a new install the sources.list.d/ directory is empty; so a user on your system with `sudo` privileges has added it post-install incorrectly.